# Which why is better or secure to check if the user logged in

Tags: php, session

I'm wondering about how do you normally check user session if the user try to login.

I use these three ways:
Considering that the userid is the userid from a database. So it should be greater than 0 if a user logged in.

```
 //With empty() function
if(empty($_SESSION['userid'])){
    echo 'you are not logged in';
}


// Check if userid session is zero
if($_SESSION['userid'] == '0'){
    echo 'you are not logged in';
}

// Check if userid is lower than 1
if($_SESSION['userid'] < '1'){
    echo 'you are not logged in';
}
```

Are these okay or do you prefer another way?

doesn't isset() function return true even userid is 0?

Thanks.

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['userid'])` ?

Comment: I think the first one

Comment: Depends on your application ;-) There might be cases where userid 0 is an user who isn't logged in… in other cases a not set userid is for not logged in users… can't say that ;-)

Comment: but isset give true even if userid is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: It doesn't matter. However, in terms of performance, you want this:

> if (isset($_SESSION['userid']))

And you want to add protection to the session. Read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering *you're* the one populating `$_SESSION['userid']` that's up to you.

Assuming you just want to know if it's there or not:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  // it's set
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  // it has a non-falsy value
}
```

It's up to how you designed the site with regards to checking `<0` or `==0` (does a valid user always have a non-zero positive ID?) And, for what it's worth, `empty` already looks for a "non falsy" value. So as long as `$_SESSION['userid']` has a value and `(bool)$_SESSION['userid'] != false` (which `0` *would* be false, `1` and greater would be true) you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine some methods in order to suppress PHP warnings, such as:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userid']) && empty($_SESSION['userid']) && ($_SESSION['userid'] > 0)) {
    //userid is set, isn't empty and is more than 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the session variable's correctly (validated what you are adding to the session etc.) then you should only need to do:

```
if( ! isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    echo 'you are not logged in';
}
```

This is because if you validated it before adding it to the session it should always be greater than 0. Is all you have to do then is if the user logs out then just use `unset` to remove then `userid`.